# getNode.transformNode beahaviour in javascript XSLT

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have an issue with `transformNode`. I am not able to understand the behavior.
In IE I have code where i am doing

```
innerListing.innerHTML = getNode(listSource.documentElement,"/OBJECTS_LIST/VECTOR_OBJECT[@name='List']").transformNode(document.XSLDocument);
```

My XSL document has two templates.

```
</xsl:stylesheet>
<xsl:template match="/">
…
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="VECTOR_OBJECT[@name='List']">
…
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My XML is a big document that has other nodes too along with `VECTOR_OBJECT[@name='List']`

Once I execute the above transformnode, it is just applying the 2nd template in IE, which is correct, but why not it is executing the first template which is matching the root node.

To do the same alternatively in chrome I am doing this:

```
document.XSLDocument=xslDocInv.responseXML;
xsltProcessor=new XSLTProcessor();
xsltProcessor.importStylesheet(document.XSLDocument);
html = xsltProcessor.transformToDocument(listSource.documentElement);
```

But in this case both the templates are being applied. I want the same functionality in IE and chrome.

Please avoid the syntactical mistake. I have given a simplified example.

Comment: With Javascript you can explain your problem here on stackoverflow by adding a minimal but complete executable code snippet your your question. That way we can see the working code in context. Currently it is not clear what for instance `getNode(listSource.documentElement,"/OBJECTS_LIST/VECTOR_OBJECT[@name='List']")` does.

Comment: I'm not certain, but I think it's not using the root template, because what your transforming doesn't include the root node. You're passing in the root ELEMENT, which is a child of the root node. Try passing `listSource` instead of `listSource.documentElement`

Comment: Martin getNode method is basially having the selectSingleNode upon the xpath given. There is a huge XML where this is the xpath for selecting the list.